# Laravel Eloquent whereDoesntHave

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm having issues using this method, I have read the docs but I am either doing something wrong or not understanding how it works or it's a bug.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
$books = Book::whereDoesntHave("author", function ($query) {
    $query->whereNotNull("died_at");
})->get();
```

Now what this is supposed to do is return all books whose authors are still alive and also all books that do not have an author, however it does the exact opposite.

I assumed `whereDoesntHave()` is supposed to check whether the model doesn't have the specified relation, in this case an `author` model with the column `died_at` having a specific value.

Instead it checks the `author` model where the column `died_at` doesn't a value.

I'm very confused about this, how is this function supposed to work exactly? Can someone please explain this to me.

Comment: You need `whereHas` instead.

Comment: But it should still return a book even if it does not have an author.

Comment: Don't you need `$query->whereNull('died_at')` - if its null author is still alive. You are using double negative, why complicate? :D

Comment: Yes that's the confusion, because looking at the query grammatically I'm saying return all books that do not have an author who has a value for died_at.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this, `doesntHave("author")` check books that doesn't have author and `whereHas` with closure check live author

```
$books = Book::doesntHave("author")->orWhereHas("author", function ($query) {
    $query->whereNotNull("died_at");
})->get();
```

Comment: You have to use `->orWhereHas("author", function(`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this for anyone who might be looking for an updated answer to a similar question. Using laravel query scopes could be the best approach here:

In your case, you want to retrieve books where the author is either alive or where there is no author. Instead of using `whereDoesntHave`, you can achieve this using a custom query scope on your `Book` model. Here's an example of how you can define a query scope for your scenario:

### Book.php

```
// Inside your Book model

public function scopeAliveAuthorsOrNoAuthor($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('author', function ($subquery) {
        $subquery->whereNull('died_at');
    })->orWhereDoesntHave('author');
}
```

you can name this function anything as long as it begins with `scope` for Laravel to identify it as query scope.

Now, in your controller, you can use this scope like this:

```
$books = Book::aliveAuthorsOrNoAuthor()->get();
```

As you can see, to apply the scope on our Builder, we can use the scope defined earlier **without the word *scope* in the beginning** and it will automagically apply the filter for us. More examples for scope would be `scopeWhereAuthorIsAlive($query)` and then call it as ``Book::whereAuthorIsAlive()```